# Coloring JTable cells based on an array created by Tetris game

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rendering, background-color

I am attempting to create a Tetris GUI. My friend wrote the backend. Up until now, we just had the tetris board (or grid as I refer to it in my code) print to the console window. In the code below I am setting up a JTable to act as the board for the Tetris game. I was wondering how I could get my JTable to render each grid element based on the grid passed from the Tetris 'game' declared in the top of the Window class. This grid is a 2D array of integer value which refer to colors enumerated in the Pieces class. Any suggestions? As of now it only prints one color.

I also posted some code for the Tetris class just so you can see the methods and parameters available there.

Here is my code (hopefully in SSCCE =p):

```
public class Window {
    JPanel cards;
    final static String SPLASHSCREEN = "SplashScreen";
    final static String MAINMENU = "MainMenu";
    final static String TETRIS = "Tetris";
    final static int GRID_ROW_HEIGHT = 30;
    final static int NUM_ROWS = 20;
    final static int NUM_COLS = 10;
    JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
    Tetris game = new Tetris(); 

    public void addComponentToWindow(Container pane) {
        // Create the "cards"
        .
        .
        .

        // SplashScreen setup
        .
        .
        .

        // MainMenu setup
        .
        .
        .

        // Tetris setup
        final JButton startGame = new JButton("START GAME");
        card3.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        card3.add(startGame, gbc2);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        startGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyRenderer());
                table.setRowHeight(GRID_ROW_HEIGHT);
                table.setFocusable(false);
                table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
                for (int i = 0; i < game.getNumCols(); i++) {
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(table.getRowHeight());
                }

                card3.add(table);
                card3.remove(0); //Removes button
                card3.revalidate(); //Redraws graphics
            }
        });

        // Sets up layout
        cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(card1, SPLASHSCREEN);
        cards.add(card2, MAINMENU);
        cards.add(card3, TETRIS);

        // Creates the actual window
        pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public Color getTableCellBackground(JTable table, int row, int col) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, col);
        Component component = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);    
        return component.getBackground();
    }

    class MyRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JTextField editor = new JTextField();
            if (value != null) {
                editor.setText(value.toString());
            }
            if (game.getCur_color().getKey() == 0) {
                editor.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else if (game.getCur_color().getKey() == 1) {
                editor.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            else if (game.getCur_color().getKey() == 2) {
                editor.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else if (game.getCur_color().getKey() == 3) {
                editor.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }
            else if (game.getCur_color().getKey() == 4) {
                editor.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            return editor;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return NUM_COLS;
        }
        public int getRowCount() {
            return NUM_ROWS;
        }        
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Tetris Class:

```
public class Tetris 
{
    int NUM_ROWS = 20;
    int NUM_COLS = 10;

    int grid[][];
    int cur_row;
    int cur_col;
    Pieces cur_color;
    Style cur_style;
    Pieces next_color;
    Style next_style;
    boolean over;

    public Tetris()
    {
        grid = new int[10][20];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 20; j ++)
            {
                grid[i][j] = Pieces.BLANK.getKey();
            }
        }

        next_color = Pieces.createColor();
        next_style = Style.createStyle();
        over = false;

        create_Piece();
    }

    public void createPiece(){...}
    public void setPiece(){...}
    public void removeRow(){...}
}
```

Along with the moveLeft, moveRight, moveDown, rotateLeft, rotateRight, printGame, and getters and setters for all fields. All the methods in the Tetris class were tested in the console and work correctly. Here is an output of what I have so far. Each time the color is different and I am pretty sure I know why, but I am having trouble thinking of how to color each cell based on the grid array created in the Tetris class.

[image]

Comment: Using JTable for this purpose is probably not the way to go, maybe consider writing a custom component and override `paintComponent()`?

Comment: I would probably use a `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, it is based on a `JLabel`, so you will need to make sure it's opaque.  Apart from that, you're going to need to change the individual cell values of the table, based on the board.  Take a look at [`TabelModel#setValueAt(Object, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: @jedyobidan You could, more easily, use a `GridLayout` and simple maintain a model of `JPanel`s ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Would setting the individual cell values of the table to an integer, then, using TableModel#getValueAt coloring the cells work?

Comment: @mstep91 Kind of.  Yes I would use `TableModel#setValueAt`, but I would let the table renderer itself.  I would take the value coming from the table determine how the cell renderer rendered the value though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This purely a proof of concept.

Basically, you already have a model of the game board.  You need to be able to model that back to the screen.

I would wrap your board model in a `TableModel` and together with `TableCellRenderer`, allow the two to work together.

The all you need to do, is update the table model accordingly when the board data changes.

If you write your relationships correctly, the border will notify the table model, which will notify the table.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class TetrisTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TetrisTable();
    }

    public TetrisTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTable table;
        private TetrisTabelModel model;
        private int currentRow = 0;
        private int blockHeight = 3;
        private int blockWidth = 3;

        public TestPane() {
            model = new TetrisTabelModel();
            table = new JTable(model);
            table.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, new TetrisTabelCellRenderer());
            table.setRowHeight(24);
            Enumeration<TableColumn> columns = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
            while (columns.hasMoreElements()) {
                TableColumn column = columns.nextElement();
                column.setPreferredWidth(24);
                column.setMinWidth(24);
                column.setMaxWidth(24);
                column.setWidth(24);
            }
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(table);

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    int col = (model.getColumnCount() - blockWidth) / 2;
                    int row = currentRow - blockHeight;
                    if (row + blockHeight >= model.getRowCount()) {
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    } else {
                        drawShape(row, col, 0);
                        currentRow++;
                        row = currentRow - blockHeight;
                        drawShape(row, col, 3);
                    }

                }

                public void drawShape(int row, int col, int color) {

                    for (int index = 0; index < blockHeight; index++) {

                        if (row >= 0 && row < model.getRowCount()) {

                            switch (index) {
                                case 0:
                                case 1:
                                    model.setValueAt(color, row, col);
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    model.setValueAt(color, row, col);
                                    model.setValueAt(color, row, col + 1);
                                    model.setValueAt(color, row, col + 2);
                                    break;
                            }

                        }
                        row++;

                    }
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();

        }
    }

    public class TetrisTabelModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private int[][] values;

        public TetrisTabelModel() {
            values = new int[20][10];
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return values.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return values[0].length;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return Integer.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return values[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            values[rowIndex][columnIndex] = (int) aValue;
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }
    }

    public class TetrisTabelCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, "", false, false, row, column);
            setOpaque(true);
            if (value != null) {
                if (value == 0) {
                    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                } else if (value == 1) {
                    setBackground(Color.RED);
                } else if (value == 2) {
                    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                } else if (value == 3) {
                    setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                } else if (value == 4) {
                    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                }
            } else {
                setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll see if I can get the Default Renderer working with my program!