# Coloring JTable cells

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, rendering

I am having trouble coloring my JTable cells. I am making a tetris game. All the functionality of the game works; button presses, keyboard interaction to move pieces, removing complete rows, etc. The output that occurs now is simply table integer values printing out  (see screenshot). These integer values refer to a color. I have the code to change the color of the cells based on said integer value in the MyRenderer class below but no coloring happens. I was wondering if there is some "rerender" method I am just not finding or do I need to build my own paint method to call?

Any suggestions?

```
    startGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            card3.remove(0); // Removes button
            model = new MyTableModel();
            table = new JTable(model);
            table.setDefaultRenderer(int.class, new MyRenderer());
            table.setRowHeight(GRID_ROW_HEIGHT);
            table.setFocusable(false);
            table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i)
                        .setPreferredWidth(table.getRowHeight());
            }
            card3.add(table);
            JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
            card3.add(pauseButton);

            pauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    game.pause();
                }
            });

            card3.setFocusable(true);
            card3.requestFocusInWindow();

            KeyListener kl = new KeyListener() {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (e.getKeyChar() == 'a' || e.getKeyChar() == 'A') {
                        game.move_Left();
                        draw_grid_first_time();
                        card3.revalidate();
                    } else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'd'
                            || e.getKeyChar() == 'D') {
                        game.move_Right();
                        draw_grid_first_time();
                        card3.revalidate();
                    } else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'q'
                            || e.getKeyChar() == 'Q') {
                        game.rotate_left();
                        draw_grid_first_time();
                        card3.revalidate();
                    } else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'e'
                            || e.getKeyChar() == 'E') {
                        game.rotate_right();
                        draw_grid_first_time();
                        card3.revalidate();
                    } else if (e.getKeyChar() == ' ') {
                        game.pause();
                    }
                }
            };
            card3.addKeyListener(kl);

            draw_grid_first_time();
            card3.revalidate(); // Redraws graphics

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if (!game.getPause()) {
                        game.move_Down();
                        draw_grid();
                        card3.revalidate(); // Redraws graphics
                    }
                }

                public void draw_grid() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < game.getNumRows(); i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < game.getNumCols(); j++) {
                            int[][] grid = game.getGrid();
                            model.setValueAt(grid[j][i], i, j);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
            if (game.isOver()) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    });

    // Sets up layout
    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cards.add(card1, SPLASHSCREEN);
    cards.add(card2, MAINMENU);
    cards.add(card3, TETRIS);

    // Creates the actual window
    pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void draw_grid_first_time() {
    for (int i = 0; i < game.getNumRows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < game.getNumCols(); j++) {
            int[][] grid = game.getGrid();
            model.setValueAt(grid[j][i], i, j);
        }
    }
}       

// Render each cell as a background color dependent on grid from tetris game
class MyRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
        JTextField editor = new JTextField();
        if (value != null) {
            editor.setText(value.toString());
        }
        if ((Integer) table.getValueAt(row, column) == 0) {
            editor.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        } else if ((Integer) table.getValueAt(row, column) == 1) {
            editor.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else if ((Integer) table.getValueAt(row, column) == 2) {
            editor.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else if ((Integer) table.getValueAt(row, column) == 3) {
            editor.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        } else if ((Integer) table.getValueAt(row, column) == 4) {
            editor.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        return editor;
    }
}
// Overwrite the Table Model to be what I want color wise
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private int[][] values = new int[NUM_COLS][NUM_ROWS];
            public int getColumnCount() {
        return NUM_COLS;
    }
            public int getRowCount() {
        return NUM_ROWS;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return values[col][row];
    }
    public void setValueAt(Object val, int row, int col) {
        values[col][19 - row] = (Integer) val;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
}
```

[image: Tetris Screenshot]

Comment: I don't understand the question. @MadProgrammer gave you a working concept in your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538237/coloring-jtable-cells-based-on-an-array-created-by-tetris-game) that did this for you. So compare how your code is different from the working example that you based your solution on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not allocate a new component in the renderer's `getTableCellRendererComponent()`. `JTable` reuses a single renderer for all cells. In your case you allocate new component for every cell, many times. For details see [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) in *How to Use Tables* tutorial. Consider this extension of `DefaultTableCellRenderer` (note that `DefaultTableCellRenderer` is an extension of `JLabel`):

```
class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBackground(getColor((Integer) value));
        return c;
    }

    private Color getColor(int value) {
        switch(value){
        case 1: return Color.RED;
        case 2: return Color.GREEN;
        //TODO the rest of colors
        }
        return Color.DARK_GRAY;
    }
}
```

Also note that since you are setting the renderer for integer column, make sure that your model actually returns a valid class in its `getColumnClass()` implementation. Otherwise, the renderer will not be used. For example `DefaultTableModel.getColumnClass()` returns `Object.class` for all columns.

`getColumnClass()` returns the class that describes the data objects stored in the specified column. This is used by `JTable`  to assign a default renderer and editor for that column. In your case, if you store integers in the model, then `getColumnClass()` should return `Integer.class`. Note however, that `Integer.class` and `int.class` are different. So `setDefaultRenderer` should correspond to the class that is returned by `getColumnClass`. In your case, either `int.Class` in both places or `Integer.Class`.

Another point, look into [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as key listeners is a lower level interface

Comment: You may also need to call setOpaque(true) on the label.

Comment: @ScottStanchfield `DefaultTableCellRenderer` calls `setOpaque(true)` in its constructor.

Comment: @Aqua Instead of `table.getValueAt(row, column))` you could simply use `value`

Comment: @Aqua What is it you mean by "make sure your model actually returns a valid class in its getColumnClass()"? I am very new to Swing graphics and don't really understand what that method even does. I don't ever use the method in my code...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks! I just initially used OP's original code and totally missed it :)

Comment: @mstep91 If the model has an integer column it should return integer class. In most cases it does not matter as the renderer usually applies `toString()` on the value to render it. However, in your case you're setting up your own renderer for a particular class. So in order to work correctly these classes should match.

Comment: @mstep91 The table will determine the render to use based the class type returned from the table model's `getColumnClass` method.  You need to make sure that this method is returning `Integer.class` for all it's columns (in your case) so your renderer is actually used.

Comment: @MadProgrammer But I never use the "getColumnClass" method or is that included in a constructor somewhere? I understand what it is you and Aqua are saying, but I don't see where I would change any code for this.

Comment: @mstep91 If you take a look at my previous answer, I use an `AbstractTableModel` (`DefaultTableModel` extends from this), I overrode the `getColumnClass` method to return `Integer.class`.  Your table model needs to do the same,

Comment: @MadProgrammer neat proof of concept by the way, +1 :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ahh I see now. Ok, I added that and still a no-go. The program still technically works and displays the integer values, it is just not setting the colors and I'm not sure why. Sorry I am very new to this so some of the simple things may take me a little longer to understand.

Comment: @mstep91 note that `int.class` and `Integer.class` are different. I noticed that you setup the renderer for `int.class`, so return the same in the `getColumnClass`

Comment: @Aqua THANKS! It works now. I should have seen that. Thanks MadProgrammer as well for the help! You two are great

Comment: @Aqua you should up-date you answer to include the discussion on the column class and correct object types, just in case some one else has a similar issue